# Problems migrate database from 4 to 5.5 mysql

Tags: mysql, migration

I have a server with 4.0 mysql version innodb engine.

I need to migrate to other server with 5.5 version (linux) ok

I dump the full database using mysqldump, when i try to restore on the 5.5 server it has a problem, because the file generate in the 4.0 set the variable on the sql scritp TYPE=INNODB and mysql 5.5 accepts only ENGINE=INNODB format on the time table creation and it abort the process.

I search on google, call any friends and nothing! the sql file has 16 gigabytes. Is not possible edit with an file editor.

error exemple:

```
CREATE TABLE tabadi ( 
nAdicao char(3) default '0', 
nSeqAdic char(3) NOT NULL default '', 
cFabricante varchar(60) NOT NULL default '', 
vDescDi varchar(15) NOT NULL default '', 
xPed int(6) NOT NULL default '0', 
nItemPed int(6) NOT NULL default '0', 
nDI varchar(12) NOT NULL default '' 
) TYPE=InnoDB
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 19: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB' at line 9

Ps: I did try to change `TYPE TO ENGINE` and its solved the problem.

Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: use an editor that can handle files that size, like notepad++ and then do a search-replace of "TYPE=InnoDB" to "ENGINE=InnoDB"

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as piping the output of `mysqldump` through a utility that can manipulate the data stream with a regular expression pattern match, like `sed` or `perl`.

```
mysqldump [options] | perl -pe 's/^\)\sTYPE=InnoDB/) ENGINE=InnoDB/' > dumpfile.sql
```

For any line that begins with `) TYPE=InnoDB` this will replace the starting portion of the line with the new string `) ENGINE=InnoDB` and leave the rest of the line intact.  It won't do anything to lines that don't match (they'll pass right through).

For quick and simple validation that this does what you want, use the `--no-data` option in `mysqldump` to dump only the table structures, not the data, and examine the resulting file.  If it looks right, you can repeat the process without `--no-data`.

A similar expression in `sed` should be this:

```
mysqldump [options] | sed 's/^) TYPE=InnoDB/) ENGINE=InnoDB/' > dumpfile.sql
```

...however, I'm not as conversant in sed as I am in perl, so I'd recommend the first approach, although I tested both versions and they appear to work identically.

Both perl and sed should be already present on any *nix system, and both are freely downloadable for Windows.  On Windows, you'll probably need `"` rather than `'` surrounding the expressions.